RPI5 - No responding / Crash during files copy
I created this topic because when I transfer files via my raspberry pi 5 8GB, after a while it stops responding.
It is server A which initiates the copy to the mount folder of server B which itself is a mounted folder of server C
Server A ---(Mount via sshfs)--> Server B (RPI 5 (here the problem)) --( Mount via Samba)-> Server C (NAS)
I had the same stack on my raspberry pi 4, I never had any problems.
I specify that I did a clean install during my migration to raspberry pi 5
I can't figure out why, I increase the swap size, which seems to delay the problem.
I have a grafana with some metrics from my raspberry pi:





How to resolve this?

Have you checked the system log after the reboot?

@goldilocks I just looked I have an out of memory error (screenshot added)

It does appear from the graph that you are running pretty close to 100% for some hours before the total failure, so that is not surprising.  If those OOM events are happening frequently during that time, it is probably a significant performance hit.  As to why swap isn't saving you, research "linux swappiness"  and you should find some tips.  You should  try and figure out where all that RAM is being used because file transfers on a NAS server shouldn't require that.

If you have no idea what it is, as a guess: If the connection to server A is faster than the connection to server C and there's enough data it could just build up in RAM, if so hopefully there is something with the software involved that can be tuned.

Hmm interesting theory, I need to do some tests to be sure. But given that my server A is in another country and my NAS is on my local network, I think it's unlikely. Plus I had exactly the same installation on my RPI 4 without any problems.

Search through those logs for all the oom-kill entries, there's probably more than one.  It can't really go directly after the real cause, since that can be difficult to impossible to discern -- eg., detecting things that leak and thus just grow endlessly would require too many resources to constantly track for, as some things may appear to do the same thing legitimately.  It has an algo for deciding in the moment which process is a "best choice". Which can be misleading, but might also provide a clue.

I found the solution to my problem. Thank you very much for your involvement

Server C was mounted with samba version forced to 2.
After removing this restriction.
The problem has disappeared, there must be an incompatibility somewhere
